# Operator Override Error

Tags: c++, c++11

I am working on the operator overload and I get this error :

```
> member function 'getAge' not viable: 'this' argument   has type 'const
> Etudiant', but function is not marked const
```

But i don't understand because i have overide my method out of my class.
I have 3 files :

My header file :

```
class Etudiant
{

string nom;
string prenom;
int age;

    public:
    Etudiant(string,string,int);
    string getNom();
    string getPrenom();
    int getAge();
};
    bool operator ==(Etudiant const& a,Etudiant const& b);
```

The Etudiant.cpp (I implement the header method )

```
Etudiant::Etudiant(string nom,string prenom,int age){
    this->nom = nom;
    this->prenom = prenom;
    this->age = age;
}


string Etudiant::getNom(){
    return this->nom;
}

string Etudiant::getPrenom(){
    return this->prenom;
}

int Etudiant::getAge(){
    return age;
}


bool operator == (Etudiant const& a,Etudiant const& b)
{
    return (a.getAge()==b.getAge());
}
```

And the main.cpp where i am testing my application

```
int main(){

Etudiant etudiant("gabriel","zaafrani",25);
Etudiant etudiant2("ilan","haddad",28);
if(etudiant==etudiant2){
    cout << "egale"<<endl;
}else{
    cout << "different"<<endl;
}
}
```

Thank you

Comment: All your `getXXX` functions should be `const` ... `int getAge() const` etc. And there's way too much `string` copying going on in your code, pass arguments as references, or if you pass by value, then `move` them in your class. And look into constructor initializer lists.

Comment: To add on the answer of @Praetorian, by declaring your getter method `const`, you are telling the user that this method won't change the internal state of the instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have a reference to a const `Etudiant` and then you are trying to call one of its non-const member functions. Member functions should be marked const if they don't modify any member variables. Like this:

```
class Etudiant {
    string nom;
    string prenom;
    int age;
public:
    Etudiant(string,string,int);
    string getNom() const;
    string getPrenom() const;
    int getAge() const;
};


string Etudiant::getNom() const {
    return this->nom;
}

string Etudiant::getPrenom() const {
    return this->prenom;
}

int Etudiant::getAge() const {
    return age;
}
```

Comment: But all the method and attribute must be const ?

Comment: Only the methods that don't change any state (instance variables) of the object. For example, getters should be const but setters can't be.

Comment: But why in the main before he wont only getter with const i just specified a const object

Comment: The error happens in the operator==() function because the parameters are declared const&.

Comment: Oki Thank you very much because I am using a const object and when i make a getter i am return a string so if I not make const i get an error ?

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
bool operator == (Etudiant const& a,Etudiant const& b)
{
    return (a.getAge()==b.getAge());
}
```

In this function, `a` and `b` are references to `const` objects. However, since `getAge()` is not a `const` member function, the compiler doesn't allow you to call `getAge()` on `a` or `b`.

As a principle, always use `const` qualifier for functions that are accessor functions. Keep the modifier functions as non-`const` member functions.

```
string getNom() const;
string getPrenom() const;
int getAge() const;
```

Update the implementations accordingly.

Comment: But all the method and attribute must be const ?

Comment: @zaafrani, any member function that does not modify the member data should be `const`. I am not sure what you mean by "attribute must be `const`".